# Objective c - textFieldDidEndEditing being called when view is disappearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to add delegate action `textFieldDidEndEditing` on `textfield`. It is working fine, but when i am trying to come out of current view while i am editing `textfield`, I don't want to call this delegate.

I tried to achieve it by `visibleViewController`, but before resigning responder, `visibleViewController` does not change.

How can I achieve this, can any one has idea?

Comment: Then set the delegate to nil, when disappear

Comment: update your question with your code what you written inside `textFieldDidEndEditing`

Comment: @KumarKl: But Before disappearing, `textFieldDidEndEditing` event gets called as it resigns responder of textfield

Comment: @KumarKl: Setitng delegate to null just before ivew dispappear worked thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@KumarKi's answer is the right way to do it, but setting textfield delegate nil on `viewWillDisappear` doesnt solve my issue.

In my case, asap I save an article view is poped out form navigation controller so `viewWillDisappear` was getting called after currentViewController is poped out, so before it is poped out i am setting it to `nil`

Answer (score 1):

Set the `UITextField delegate` to `nil` at

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear{
    [super viewWillDisappear];
    textfield.delegate = nil;
}
```

**NOTE:** Officially posting my comment. It will be useful for someone.